# When are python sunder names used?

Tags: python, enums, naming-conventions, underscores

In Python, there are conventions for single leading underscore, double leading underscore, double leading + double trailing underscore, and single trailing underscore.  Many of those are outlined in the answers at *[What is the meaning of a single- and a double-underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1301346/974555)*.

But what is the meaning or convention for single leading + single trailing underscore?  I've first seen their use in the [`enum` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#supported-sunder-names):

> 8.13.15.3.2. Supported `_sunder_` names
>
> - `_name_` – name of the member
> - `_value_` – value of the member; can be set / modified in **new**
> - `_missing_` – a lookup function used when a value is not found; may be overridden
> - `_ignore_` – a list of names, either as a list() or a str(), that will not be transformed into members, and will be removed from the final class
> - `_order_` – used in Python 2/3 code to ensure member order is consistent (class attribute, removed during class creation)
> - `_generate_next_value_` – used by the Functional API and by auto to get an appropriate value for an enum member; may be overridden

I have not seen such single-leading-single-trailing underscore *sunder* names before.  Are they treated in any special way, or otherwise have an implied meaning that is distinct from any of the other underscore-related naming conventions?  How are they different from having no underscores at all?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They are not treated in any special way. They are being used by the enum module so as to

- Not to be accidentally overridden

e.g.

```
class Status(Enum):
    alive = auto()
    dead = auto()
    missing = auto()
```

You can see that `Status.missing` and `Status._missing_` are different objects. If the Enum method `_missing_` were named `missing`, we would have overridden it.

- not appear as private. The name `_value` in python is considered private. To express that these are not private (which again, a user might want an enum value to be private), they are instead given sunder names
- other alternatives such as `__double_leading_underscore` and `__dunder__` also have special meanings in python as you stated above. `_sunder_` methods in `Enum` act something like the `__dunder__` protocols of pure python, but aren't reserved by the language.

Basically, it's an option to avoid attribute name conflicts without giving the wrong impression.

Comment: But `_name_` and `_value_` are attributes on the `Enum` type, not on the metaclass `EnumMeta`.  `class Test(Enum): a = 0`, then `Test.a._name_ == 'a'`, `Test._name_` however yields `AttributeError`. I can see how attribute name conflicts need to be prevented on `EnumMeta`, but where is the conflict risk on the resulting `Enum` type?

Comment: Besides, `Test.a.name` and `Test.a.value` *also* work, so it appears `_name_` and `_value_` are just synonyms for `name` and `value`, respectively.

Comment: As the author of `Enum`, I approve this answer.  ;-)

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the popular Jupyter REPL and visualization framework (which includes IPython under its mighty aegis) makes somewhat extensive use of “sunder”–named properties and methods, e.g. `_repr_jpeg_` and `_repr_html_`, in order to provide bespoke rendering for compliant Python objects in its enhanced REPL environment (q.v. details of same at https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html supra.)

Comment: @gerrit:  The answer to your questions is more involved than I want to get into in a comment.  If you ask it as a new question I would be happy to answer.